# How to Parse ical file (.ics) with the ical4j API in Android?

Tags: android

I am developing an application that download the schedule calendar file of specific user to the phone memory and shows to the user in different user friendly formats.

1. Get the user's ID entered in the UI
2. Generate the user's unique calendar URL
3. Retrieve the calendar file over HTTP
4. Save the file locally
5. Display the calendar data to the user
       Read the file from disk that you saved directly from the web
       Parse the data with iCal4j and display in whatever UI format you like

I have downloaded file to the phone memory , the file is `.ics` file that contains some header,time zone,tags link html and original schedule information.Now I need to parse this ical file with ical4j.I have added the `ical4j JAR API` and also the dependent APIs to my project. But still finding it difficult to work on it. I used information from link below and tried to add the sample project code but it seems to have errors

`http://wiki.modularity.net.au/ical4j/index.php?title=Android`

So is there any way to parse the ical file with `ical4j`?and i can use it to re Can anyone provide me with some sample code so that I can learn how to use this `API`? Or do you have any idea like how can I do it?

Hope to get answer today, I need your help badly.

Thanks

Rob

Answer (score 0):

I always have problems with using external libraries inAndroid projects, ald always ended on writing own implementation :/

ical is very simple, so if you know what fields you need it may be better to write own class instead of using full of unused features library.

That's only idea...

Comment: well, i am not that good in it so I am still waiting for further ideas